# Looping through an AntDesign Row/Form; when an option is selected from dropdown, all of the other Rows Values get changed

Tags: reactjs, typescript, antd, use-state

I have a Form from Ant Design and inside the form I am looping through part of it to create multiple Rows, but when one value gets changed in a dropdown list - all the other labels. are changed in each row. The actual value isn't saved into seriesList State, it is just showing the same label in the dropdown.

[image]

I am setting the initial state here:

```
  const [seriesList, setSeriesList] = useState([
        {
            seriesId: uuidv4(),
            index: "watcher_events",
            color: "",
            type: "",
            meta: {
                watcher_name: "",
                watcher_type: "",
                watcher_id: ""
            },
            aggregation_field: "",
            filters: [{
                field: 'event_type',
                operator: 'is',
                value: ""
            }],
        },
    ]);
```

The function which adds a new row when Add Series is clicked

```
    const handleAddClick = () => {
        setSeriesList([...seriesList, {
            seriesId: uuidv4(),
            index: "watcher_events",
            color: "",
            type: "",
            meta: {
                watcher_name: "",
                watcher_type: "",
                watcher_id: ""
            },
            aggregation_field: "",
            filters: [{
                field: 'event_type',
                operator: 'is',
                value: ""
            }],
        }]);
    };
```

The function which updates the correct series with the color selected.

```
    const handleColor = (e: any, index: any) => {
        const list = [...seriesList];
        list[index].color = e;
        setSeriesList(list);
    };
```

The list of color options that I am looping through and showing in the dropdown.

```
export const chartColorOptionsV2 = [
    {
        label: 'Green',
        value: '#2AB596',
    },
    {
        label: 'Orange',
        value: '#F5A624',
    },
    {
        label: 'Sky Blue',
        value: '#53B9E9',
    },
    {
        label: 'Pink',
        value: '#E2507A',
    },
    {
        label: 'Navy',
        value: '#275FAD',
    }
];
```

The JSX where the form is and rows I am looping through:

```
 <Button icon={<PlusOutlined/>}
                            size={"large"}
                            onClick={handleAddClick}>Add Series</Button>
                    {seriesList.map((x, i) => {
                        return (
                            <Row
                                key={i}
                                wrap={false}
                                style={{
                                    marginTop: 5
                                }}>
                                <Form.Item
                                    name={"index"}
                                    key={`index: ${i}`}
                                    hasFeedback
                                    initialValue={x.index}
                                >
                                    <Select
                                        placeholder="Select an index"
                                        size={"large"}
                                        style={{
                                            width: 200
                                        }}
                                        onChange={(e: any) => handleIndex(e, i)}
                                    >
                                        {indexOptions.map((option) => (
                                            <Select.Option key={option.value + i}
                                                           value={option.value}>{option.label}</Select.Option>
                                        ))}
                                    </Select>
                                </Form.Item>
                                <Form.Item
                                    name={"watcher"}
                                    key={`watcher: ${i}`}
                                    hasFeedback
                                    rules={[{required: true, message: 'Please select a field'}]}
                                    className={styles.filterMenuWatcherType}
                                >
                                    <WaveValuesAutoComplete
                                        index={seriesList[i].index}
                                        field={determineIndex(seriesList[i].index)}
                                        dropdownMatchSelectWidth={400}
                                        style={{
                                            width: 200,
                                            marginLeft: 5
                                        }}
                                        size={"large"}
                                        showCount={true}
                                        onChange={(e: any) => handleWatcher(e, i)}
                                    />
                                </Form.Item>
                                <Form.Item name="color"
                                           key={`color: ${i}`}
                                           rules={[{required: true, message: 'Please select a color'}]}
                                           hasFeedback
                                >
                                    <Select
                                        key={`color: ${i}`}
                                        style={{
                                            width: 200,
                                            marginLeft: 5,
                                        }}
                                        placeholder="Select a color"
                                        size={"large"}
                                        onChange={(e: any) => handleColor(e, i)}
                                    >
                                        {chartColorOptionsV2.map((e: any) => (
                                            <Select.Option key={e.value + i} value={e.value}>{e.label}</Select.Option>
                                        ))}
                                    </Select>
                                </Form.Item>
                                {seriesList.length !== 1 &&
                                    <Tooltip title={"Click to remove this trace."}>
                                        <Button icon={<DeleteOutlined/>}
                                                size={"large"}
                                                style={{
                                                    width: 50,
                                                    marginLeft: 5,
                                                }}
                                                onClick={() => handleRemoveClick(i)}
                                        />
                                    </Tooltip>}
                            </Row>
                        );
                    })}
                    <div style={{marginTop: 20}}>{JSON.stringify(seriesList)}</div>
                    <Divider/>
                    <Form.Item>
                        <Button type="primary"
                                htmlType="submit"
                                size={"large"}
                        >
                            Add Chart
                        </Button>
                    </Form.Item>
                </Form>
            </Space>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`<Form.Item name="color"`. I'm not wrong this is causing the issue. Since you have same `name` for field in each row, when you change any one it will change all the others. When you wrap any field with `<Form.Item>` and add `name` attribute, antd Form controls the field. In order to fix it, make sure you have different name for each field i.e. `` name={`color_${index}`} `` or if you are controlling each field value and handling its onChange function then just remove name from Form.Item.
Hope this will resolve your issue

Comment: Thank you, this resolved my issue! I assumed providing a unique key for each dropdown would do the same. Thanks again!